# How do i split a Qstring to new line

Tags: c++, qt, split, qstring

Spliting a string to a new line in Qt c++

Qstring is

```
Qstring str = "diskinfo: Node: ASHUTOSH-PC, Description: Local Fixed Disk, FreeSpace: 418581491712, Name: C:, Size  : 499875049472  Node: ASHUTOSH-PC, Description: CD-ROM Disc, FreeSpace: , Name: D:, Size  :   Node: ASHUTOSH-PC, Description: Local Fixed Disk, FreeSpace: 324982935552, Name: E:, Size  : 487687450624  Node: ASHUTOSH-PC, Description: CD-ROM Disc, FreeSpace: 0, Name: F:, Size  : 553459712"
```

Expected out put is

```
  "diskinfo: Node: ASHUTOSH-PC, Description: Local Fixed Disk, FreeSpace: 420842713088, Name: C:, Size  : 499875049472
             Node: ASHUTOSH-PC, Description: CD-ROM Disc, FreeSpace: , Name: D:, Size  : 
             Node: ASHUTOSH-PC, Description: Local Fixed Disk, FreeSpace: 324858568704, Name: E:, Size  : 487687450624 
             Node: ASHUTOSH-PC, Description: CD-ROM Disc, FreeSpace: 0, Name: F:, Size  : 553459712"
```

That is it should split only when there is space  not when there is a comma followed by space? i.e it should start with Node in every line? Can any one help How is this to be done in Qt c++

now following is my code Written:

```
   QString Utils::getDiskSpace( )
     {
          static QString diskSpaceCmd ( qgetenv("WINDIR")
                               + "\\system32\\wbem\\wmic logicaldisk get name, freespace, size, description /format:csv");

 QProcess proc;
 QByteArray qba;
 QString out_str;
 QString newStr;


 proc.start(diskSpaceCmd);

 if(proc.waitForFinished(-1))
     {
      qba = proc.readAllStandardOutput();
      qba = qba.trimmed();
      qba =qba.replace('\r',' ');
      QString myString =qba;

      QStringList myStringList = myString.split("\n");

      QStringList descriptions = myStringList[0].split(",");

      for(int index = 1;index < myStringList.length();index++)
      {
          QStringList data = myStringList[index].split(",");
          QStringList out;
          for(int ind_2 = 0; ind_2 < data.length(); ind_2++)
              out.push_back(descriptions[ind_2] + ": " +data[ind_2]);
           out_str += out.join(", ");
      }


      out_str = out_str.replace("Node:", "\nNode:");
      QStringList list;

      if( !out_str.startsWith( '\n' ) )
              out_str+=' ';

      for( int i = 0; i < out_str.count( '\n' ); ++i ){
          list << out_str.section( '\n', i, i, QString::SectionIncludeTrailingSep ).simplified();
      }
      foreach( QString out_str, list )
          QLOG_DEBUG()<<"Out_Str" << out_str;
 }
 QString diskSpace(out_str);
 return (diskSpace);
```

}

Comment: [`QString::replace`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#replace-8) ?

Comment: Why should we use replace I dont want to replace any thing I want to split only when there is only space. i.e Before word Node there is a space .. i want to seperate only at that space?  space should not have any other delimeters like , (comma) ,(Semicolon ) before it ,

Comment: `replace(" Node:", "\nNode:")` - however this would affect the beginning of the string (e.g. '\n' after "diskinfo").

Comment: yes I will replae a Qstring . then I need to convert it to QStringlist to split?

Comment: So what do you want to get in the end: `QString` with '\n's or `QStringList` with each item being 'Node:...' ?

Comment: At end Need to return a Qstring with each item being starting with 'Node...'

Comment: @YuriyIvaskevych can this be done using Json array?

Comment: Yes, if you need this in json look at [`QJsonArray::append()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonarray.html#append).

Comment: I am new at Json But do i need to create a Json object

Comment: Yes, and probably `QJsonDocument`. Take a look at [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-json-savegame-example.html) using these QJson-classes.

Answer (score 0):

Might sound obvious but, how about using [QString::split](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#split)?

```
QStringList strList = str.split(QRegularExpression("\WNode"),QString::SkipEmptyParts);
```

Then you can add "Node" word at the beginning of each string with `prepend`.

This is how I would do it.

Comment: Is it possible to convert to JSon array?

Comment: With several small string parse logics, you can shape the list at hand into any form you want. QString provides many useful functions like "left", "right", "mid", "chop", "append", "prepend" etc. I recommend you have a look at QString documentation page, I think everything you need is there.